# Graphics API version mismatch

Tags: r, plot

I have a big problem

I update R to the latest version.

After updating, every time i try to plot something with whatsoever kind of graphic function( even with the basic plot) i get this error

```
Error: Graphics API version mismatch
```

these are my session info

```
 R version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Italian_Italy.1252 
[2] LC_CTYPE=Italian_Italy.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=Italian_Italy.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                  
[5] LC_TIME=Italian_Italy.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods  
[7] base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.3.2 tools_3.3.2   
Note: no visible binding for global variable 'x' 
Note: no visible binding for global variable 'envir'
```

All packages installed are updated to the latest version available

Comment: You have a *ton* of packages loaded and attached. This makes it hard to know what causes the error. Reduce this as much as possible.

Comment: update. I started a new R session. The problem is the compiler_3.3.2 ??

Comment: Don't "update" R.  Uninstall and re-install completely.  It will fix your problem.

Comment: WIth R 4.3.0 I am having the same problem.  I'm using Ubuntu 22.04 with debian package management.  I've reinstalled R and all packages from debian binaries.  I suspect a graphics incompatibility related to javascript / sparklines package / rshiny but haven't been able to nail it down yet.

Comment: Update: Thanks to Dirk Eddelbuettel it's solved by installing source packages `ragg` and `svglite` (you won't need the second if not using it explicitly).

Comment: @FrankHarrell can you tell what did you do more specifically, please? I've tried by ´sudo apt reinstall´ [and reinstalling what has to be reinstalled using the newer RStudio version](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/debian/#supported-branches). Can you direct me to where Dirk helped you? Was it here on SE? On github? etc. I am considering opening a ticket at r-sig-debian.

Comment: I just used `install.packages()` for those two.